# How to exclude all folders with specific name when updating SVN working copy?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, directory, ignore, updating

I am using Tortoise SVN.

There is a *very* large repository with a *very big folder tree* in my office institution. My computer only has about 64GB free space (SSD), while the repo is about 100GB. The problem is, that repository has *many* folders (called **Concepts**) that include many very large tif files (kept for safekeeping - programmers only use compressed versions of those pictures).

It is illogical to **update my working copy** using **Update to revision** context command, and deselect all of the "Concepts" folders in the source tree every time I need to update my working copy.

Example folder structure:

```
\folder
    \child
        \Concepts
    \child1
        \Concepts
    \child2
        \Concepts
    \child3
        \Concepts
\folder1
    \childOther
        \grandchild
            \Concepts
        \grandchild1
            \Concepts
        \grandchild2
            \Concepts
```

I *cannot* just exclude all the tif files, because they are being used in other folders.

So my final question is:
How to **exclude all the folders with specific name** from the tree, **when updating my working copy** from Tortoise SVN repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature does not exist.  The command line versions of [`svn checkout`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) and [`svn update`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) do not have a "filter" option, so it stands to reason that TortoiseSVN would not offer you this ability either.

What you're really asking for is a [sparse checkout](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html), one where you have none of the "Concepts" folders in your working copy and SVN knows to never pull them down from the repository.  To create one, you have two options:

1. If you haven't checked out your working copy yet, then you can use the built-in support for this in TortoiseSVN's "Checkout" dialog (from the above link):

   > To easily select only the items you want for the checkout and force the resulting working copy to keep only those items, click the *Choose items...* button. This opens a new dialog where you can check all items you want in your working copy and uncheck all the items you don't want. The resulting working copy is then known as a sparse checkout. **An update of such a working copy will not fetch the missing files and folders but only update what you already have in your working copy.**

   In other words, select all directories except your "Concepts" directory and execute the checkout.  Then, when you need to update later on, those directories will not be pulled down.
2. If you have already checked out the code, you can turn your working copy into a sparse checkout by using TortoiseSVN's "Update to Revision" dialog.  Right-click on the "Concepts" folder you do not want in your working copy, select *Update to Revision*, and select an *Update Depth* of "Exclude."  That will remove it from your working copy and further updates will not pull it down again.

If, sometime later, you ever *do* want one of the "Concepts" folders, you can make it part of your working copy.  The easiest way to do so is right-click the parent directory of the folder you want to pull down, click *Repo-browswer*, and then right-click on the "Concepts" folder and select *Update item to revision*.  In that dialog, select an *Update Depth* of "Working copy" and click "OK".

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! It's a shame there is no option to do this in some kind of easy way.
I will try the _Update Depth of "Exclude."_ option ASAP, and will see if it worked. :)

Comment: Happy to help.  If that answered your question, don't forget to mark my answer as accepted to help others in the future

Comment: Sure, I am pretty familiar how StackOverflow works :) So now I did a new Checkout, and deselected all the Concepts folders. The Checkout was successful, and quite fast (I already got used to deselecting all the Concepts folders, ha). And now someone modified one of the Concepts folders (added an item).
So should I just update my working copy (all the Concepts folders will be ommited)? Or do I need to do this strange step you wrote before:
"_You'll have to explicitly go to their parent directory, click Update to Revision, and select an Update Depth of "Immediate children, including folders"._"?

Comment: Just perform an update; if you did the checkout right (and it sounds like you did), then you won't get their update.  The "strange step" is only if you, at some point later, *do* want one of the Concepts folders in your working copy.

Comment: Well, it actually worked. Thank you very much! You saved me those 10 minutes I was spending every day while updating and deselecting those damn Concepts.. :D
And it would be nice if you could edit the post and explain the "strange step" with the explanation you gave me in the comment, so that everyone understands later. :) Thanks again!

Comment: You're right, I re-read that section and that made no sense.  Fixed, hopefully :)